# Exit jshell with error code

Tags: java-9, jshell

How do I `/exit` a [jshell](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jshell.htm) session with a non-zero error code?

- `/exit` yields: *Process finished with exit code 0*
- `/exit 1` yields: *Process finished with exit code 0*
- `throw new Error("1")` yields: *java.lang.Error thrown: 1 at (#24:1)` and Process finished with exit code 0*
- `System.exit(1)` yields: *State engine terminated. Restore definitions with: /reload -restore ... and the jshell session is not terminated.*

A bash command like `set -e` is not available.

Comment: There's now an issue at the JDK bug tracker: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8185840

Comment: Right, this enhancement is covered under JDK-8185840 which we plan to fix in the next release JDK 18.3 (aka JDK 10).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now, JShell shipping with **JDK 10** and later introduced a new version of `/exit` that takes an optional snippet as an argument. That snippet is evaluated to the error code that will be returned to the calling process. See http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/kulla-dev/2017-November/002129.html for details.

Here is the help text for the new `/exit` commands using jdk-10+ea-33:

```
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 10
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> /help exit
|
|  /exit
|
|  Leave the jshell tool.  No work is saved.
|  Save any work before using this command
|
|  /exit
|       Leave the jshell tool.  The exit status is zero.
|
|  /exit <integer-expression-snippet>
|       Evaluate the snippet.  If the snippet fails or is not an integer expression,
|       display the error.  Otherwise leave the jshell tool with the
|       value of the expression as the exit status

jshell> /exit 123
|  Goodbye (123)
```

Note for **JDK 9**: *You can't use `/exit` to exit a jshell session on JDK 9 with a non-zero error code. See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8185840 for details.*