# jshell always exits with zero status code

Tags: java, linux, jshell

I use Linux and have noticed that jshell always exits with code 0 even if the java expression is invalid:

```
$ echo "invalid java expression" | jshell -
Error:
';' expected 
invalid java expression;
            ^
$ echo $?
0
```

Is it possible to force it to exit with a non-zero code somehow?
I've read the help but have found nothing about it.

Comment: Try something like `echo 'int exitCode = 0; try { int n = Integer.parseInt("GOO"); } catch(Exception e) {exitCode = -1;} /exit exitCode' | jshell -i || echo "There was an error"`

Comment: Sadly, jshell does not behave like a regular REPL in other languages. Neither does it support shebang, nor does it automatically set the exit status of its process to a non-zero value when it encountered an error.

Comment: related [Exit jshell with error code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44620232/85421)

Comment: *"Sadly, jshell does not behave ..."* ... Somewhere, somehow, someone thinks that is a feature /-8!

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way is to run command '/exit' with proper argument.

```
echo "/exit -1" | jshell
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution doesn't necessarily answer the question but can be used as a workaround.
It is based on redirecting standard and error output of **jshell** to  corresponding files and evaluate them after the execution.

Create temporary files:

```
$ stdout=$(mktemp); stderr=$(mktemp)
```

Unsuccessful execution:

```
$ echo "invalid java expression" | jshell - 1>$stdout 2>$stderr
```

Evaluate the results:

```
$ cat $stdout 
$ cat $stderr 
Error:
';' expected
invalid java expression;
            ^
```

Successful execution:

```
$ echo "System.out.println(\"valid java expression\")" | jshell - 1>$stdout 2>$stderr
$ cat $stdout 
valid java expression
$ cat $stderr 
$
```